# How does scoping work in R?

Tags: r, scoping

```
a <- 10
f <- function(){
    a <<- 3
    function() {
      a <<- 15
      a <- 5
      return(a)
    }
}
g <- f()
g()
a
```

When I run the above code I get the following output:

> 5
>
> 15

Can someone please explain how the second output is 15 instead of 3? And the same code returns 10 for a when I do not use "<<-" in the function f.

Comment: This should help! http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: I'm going to guess that the main piece of the puzzle that you're confused about is that in R, the last expression in the function **is** the return value of that function, which in your case is the internal anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just see what your function `f` returns.

```
f()
function() {
      a <<- 15
      a <- 5
      return(a)
    }
<environment: 0x000000001f1c7898>
```

So when you assign this result, a function, to `g` it becomes that function in the output above. The code line `a <<- 3` is **never** executed when you call `g`.
In other words, the second output is explained in the same fashion the first output is explained, `g` sets the variable `a` that exists in the `globalenv` to `15` and returns a value of variable `a <- 5` created in its own environment.

**EDIT.**
Note that if, like Dason says in his comment, print `a` before calling `g` its value has changed to `3` like you expect it in your question. The code line `a <<- 3` was indeed executed when `f` was called.

```
g <- f()   # call 'f'

a          # print 'a', the value has changed
[1] 3

g()        # now call 'g'
[1] 5

a          # and the value of 'a' changed again
[1] 15
```

Comment: `a <<- 3` might not be executed when you call g() but it executed when you call f().  If you add `print(a)` before and after the line that goes `g <- f()` it might illustrate what's going on a bit better.

Comment: @Dason That's true, maybe my answer is a bit terse, I'll edit it and include that suggestion.